# Cannot get my data in express and react error: failed to execute feth on window

Tags: reactjs, express

I created in API in node js for my react app
When I run my app on browser it shows me this error:
[image]

This is my useEffect function:

```
async function getMyData() {
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/get-sarbatoare', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'X- Requested - With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
            },
        })
        const serverData = await response.json();
        setData(serverData)
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        getMyData();
    }, [])
```

and this is my app.js file with express:

```
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const PORT = 8080 || process.env.PORT;
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
app.use("*", cors())

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log('servarul ruleaza pe portul' + PORT));
app.get('/get-sarbatoare', (req, res) => res.json({ imgIcon, ts }));
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you add your getMyData inside the effec and try?

```
    useEffect(() => {

       async function getMyData() {
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/get-sarbatoare', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'X- Requested - With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
            },
        })
        const serverData = await response.json();
        setData(serverData)
      }
        getMyData();
    }, [])
```